# How to Automate the Authorised networks update of my Public IP on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-sdk

I am using Cloud SQL as a data warehouse for some ELT processes.
But each time my ISP changes my Home/Office IP (Daily), I need to log into the console web interface and Allowlist my IP under `Authorised networks`.

**Question**: Any suggestions on automating this process. like `PowerShell` script/BAT

I also need to maintain the other IPs, so I cannot use the SDK since it will delete/ overwrite the different IPs in Authorised Networks.

I am the project owner, but I can't change the instance or use Cloud SQL Proxy since the ETL stuff has the IP hardcoded `35.xxx.xxx.xxx` vs proxy `127.0.0.1`

[image]

Also the problem with using `gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_ID] --authorized-networks=[NETWORK_RANGE_1],[NETWORK_RANGE_2]...` [image]

So in need to get the list first and pass it to a variable...

Comment: Use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy and then you will not need to update the IP whitelist.

Comment: Thanks, John. Yeah, it is the better option... BUT in my case using Cloud SQL Auth Proxy changes the connection strings for some ETL Jobs that have been hardcoded (Legacy Systems) e.g.  Imagine a billion report pointing to external IP and the inability to change all of them to 127.0.0.1 [I will update my question to reflect this issue]

Comment: @BOB posted an answer , Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, you can’t use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy so, To establish a connection with a Cloud SQL instance on its public network you need  to establish an authorized network.

You can refer to this Google public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks#authorized-networks) where there is a whole description of how to configure public IP for your Cloud SQL Instance.The IP address can be of a range in CIDR notation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line of code used to get from an existing instance to add in new one:

```
gcloud sql instances describe <cloud-sql-instance> --format=json | jq -r '.settings.ipConfiguration.authorizedNetworks[]|select(.name|contains("<NetworkName>"))| "\(.name):\(.value)/32"' | paste -d',' -s -
```